Downgrading to solana versions <2 with agave-install
Let's say I just installed Solana tools version 2.0.19 with agave (the latest stable version as of today is 2.0.19):
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)"
Now I need to revert to an older version of tools for a compatibility issue:
agave-install init 1.18.17
This works great, but now agave-install is gone, because 1.18 didn't have it:
agave-install init 2.0.19
zsh: command not found: agave-install

And solana-install can't upgrade me to back to 2+
solana-install init 2.0.19 
⚠️  solana-install is deprecated and will be discontinued when v1.18 is no longer supported. Please switch to Agave: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/wiki/Agave-Transition

Error: "Unknown release: 2.0.19"


So now I have to run the installer again, and do so every time I downgrade to 1.18 or earlier and then want to go back to 2+. Is there a better way?

I don't think so there is any, Been having this same trouble
